# How to clear a particular row from a Gridview on display after clicking on Delete Button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, gridview, webforms

Below is my aspx code associated with Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HorizontalAlign="Center" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting"  HeaderStyle-BackColor="#00a400" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
        <Columns>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Product_No" HeaderText="Product No" />
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
         <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="120px"
          ImageUrl='<%#"data:Image/png/jpg/jpeg/gif/bmp;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("Product_Image")) %>' />
         </ItemTemplate>         
         </asp:TemplateField>        
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Product_Name" HeaderText="Product" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Barcode_No" HeaderText="Barcode" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Product_Category_Name" HeaderText="Category" />
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price" >
         <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID ="TextBox3" runat="server" Width="80px" DataField="Product_Price" Text='<%#string.Format("{0:0.00}",Eval("Product_Price"))%>'/>
          <asp:Label ID="Label4" Text="AUD" runat="server"></asp:Label>
          <asp:Button ID ="Button10" runat="server" OnClick="Price_Update_Click" ValidationGroup="UpdatePrice" CommandArgument="Button11" CommandName="Update"  Text="Update" />
          <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox3" ErrorMessage="Must be greater than 0.09 .. Cannot accept integer or character or more than 2 numbers after decimal" Operator="GreaterThan" Type="Currency" ValueToCompare="0.09" Display="Dynamic" />
          <%--<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"  runat="server" ErrorMessage="Numbers with only 2 digits after decimal" ControlToValidate="TextBox3" ValidationExpression="^\d{1,9}\.\d{1,2}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>--%>               
          </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity" >
          <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID ="TextBox4" runat="server" Width="60px" DataField="Product_Quantity" Text='<%#Eval("Product_Quantity")%>' />
          <asp:Button ID ="Button11" runat="server" OnClick="Quantity_Update_Click" ValidationGroup="UpdateQuantity" CommandArgument="Button12" CommandName="Update"  Text="Update" />
          <%--<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox4" ErrorMessage="Must be greater than 0 .. Cannot accept decimal or character" Operator="GreaterThan" Type="Integer" ValueToCompare="0" Display="Dynamic"  />--%>
          <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Cannot accept decimal or character" ControlToValidate="TextBox4" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]*$" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator> 
          <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server"></asp:Label>     
          </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Grocery_Branch_Name" HeaderText="Branch" />
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remove Product">
          <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Button ID="Button12" runat="server" OnClick="Delete_Click" ValidationGroup="DeleteProduct" CommandArgument="Button6" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" CausesValidation ="false" />
          </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          </Columns>
         </asp:GridView>
```

Then below is cs code associated with deleting a product through stored procedure:

```
 protected void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
            string ProductId = row.Cells[0].Text;

            string CS;
            CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Grocery_DemoConnectionString"].ConnectionString; ;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DeleteProduct", con);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductNo", ProductId);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox("Product has been removed from the stock");
}



 protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

The Delete Stored Procedure is working successfully and a particular product in is being deleted from the database table on Delete Click Event. The message box also gets displayed "Product has been removed from the stock"

However, the issue is that the Gridview still displays that particular product row even though that particular product has been already deleted from the database.

If I manually click on Refresh button, then that particular deleted product row is not displayed in the Gridview anymore.

But what I want to achieve is that after clicking on Delete button, that particular product row shouldn't be displayed in the Gridview anymore so that I don't have to manually solve it through clicking on Refresh button.

If there is something I need to include in my cs code OR aspx code then
kindly do mention it so that I can try and test it out.

Comment: Update the source data and rebind it to the GridView.

Comment: Can you show a syntax example so that I can clearly understand